# Failed to install opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv, homebrew

I am attempting to install opencv. I followed the steps here http://www.mobileway.net/2015/02/14/install-opencv-for-python-on-mac-os-x/

Everything went well, except when I attempted to install opencv by

```
$ brew install opencv
```

The error message showed:

```
==> Installing opencv from homebrew/science
==> Installing dependencies for homebrew/science/opencv: mpfr, libmpc, isl, gcc, sphinx-doc, cmake, eigen, jpeg, libpng, libtiff, ilmbase, openexr, homebrew/python/numpy
==> Installing homebrew/science/opencv dependency: mpfr
==> Using the sandbox
Error: mpfr cannot be built with any available compilers.
Install GNU's GCC
brew install gcc
```

**UPDATE**
As I tried more and install gcc by `brew install gcc`, I have this error:

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
No changes to formulae.

Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
==> Installing dependencies for gcc: mpfr, libmpc, isl
==> Installing gcc dependency: mpfr
==> Using the sandbox
Error: mpfr cannot be built with any available compilers.
Install GNU's GCC
brew install gcc
```

And as I deleted all of the above paths and run `brew update` and `brew install gcc`, I still got the same error:

```
==> Installing dependencies for gcc: mpfr, libmpc, isl
==> Installing gcc dependency: mpfr
==> Using the sandbox
Error: mpfr cannot be built with any available compilers.
Install GNU's GCC
brew install gcc
```

Could someone help me identify the problem and how to solve it? Thank you!

Comment: type the command you see in red ...

Comment: Thanks. I tried `$brew install gcc`, but it pops up the same error - `Error: mpfr cannot be built with any available compilers.
Install GNU's GCC
  brew install gcc`

Comment: Do you have macOS command-line tools installed? They should provide you with a version of GCC.

If not, try installing them by running `xcode-select --install`

Comment: Thank you. I did `$ xcode-select --install`, and it showed `Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
`. As I tried $brew install gcc`, it still came up with the same error.

Comment: First debugging step - try a little `brew doctor` to see if it's reporting significant warnings/errors - it sounds like bits & pieces in /usr/local are root owned and it's interfering with brew's install process. Brew installs opencv on my laptop (sierra, homebrew 1.1.1) without needing to compile. (mind you 'works on my machine' comments like this are a little frustrating to people)